# Mongoose validation exception not caught

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean

I'm setting up a user registration within a MEAN app. However, I'm struggling with error handling, especially with Mongoose validation.

In the following code, when I provide a wrong email to my API, exception thrown by mongoose is not caught in my block.

```
try {
    User.save(function (err, user) {
        if (err) throw err; //This exception in not catched :(

        res.status(200).json({
            _status: 200,
            _content: {
                message: "OK",
                data: user
            }
        });
    });
} catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
        _status: 400,
        _content: {
            message: err.toString()
        }
    });
}
```

How can I catch this exception?

Comment: Can you check what your err is returning by doing console.log(err); inside your User.save callback

Comment: Hi firsts lines of the console outputs me this :
`if (err) throw err;
                                       ^
ValidationError: This email is not valid`

Comment: You will have to use try catch inside your callback.

Comment: Thanks @yalamber this tip worked. But I don't understand why. Are errors thrown within callback not visible from the outside ?

Comment: When the try catch block is executed, there is no error. Since your User.save is asynchronous it will only throw error when callback is executed Later. You might need to look in to asynchronous nature of javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you do it this way instead:

```
User.save(function (err, user) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({
        _status: 400,
        _content: {
            message: err.toString()
        }
    });
  }
  res.status(200).json({
    _status: 200,
    _content: {
      message: "OK",
      data: user
    }
  });
});
```

Your code won't work because try catch won't be able to catch exceptions thrown inside your callback.

Comment: Thanks for the help I'll do it that way !